# What is the meaning of "on the economy side from budget airlines"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The airline is battling strong competition from Asian and Middle Eastern carriers, and **on the economy side from budget airlines**, which have grown in number in Asia.

Please tell me what "on the economy side from budget airlines" means.

Whole story:http://www.taipeitimes.com/News/biz/archives/2013/07/10/2003566733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me reorder the words (and split the sentence into two) to make clear what belongs together:

- (In business/first class,) the airline is battling strong competition from middle eastern carriers.
- On the economy side, the airline is battling strong competition from budget airlines.

Meaning:

- The business class passengers are using e.g. Emirates, because either they are getting better service for the same price, or paying less.
- The economy passengers are using low-fare carriers (also called "budget airlines") like Tiger Airways, because for them, each penny saved is a penny earned.

Perhaps, to make it more clear: the construction

`to battle competition from sth./s.o.`

can't be split, because that would distort the meaning of the whole sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the information provided before the sentence in question:

> Singapore Airlines (SIA) yesterday unveiled new seats and other
> in-flight amenities in all classes as part of a sweeping upgrade of
> its cabins in an attempt to stay competitive. Passengers on selected
> flights between Singapore and London will be the first to experience
> the improved seats and entertainment system, wider TV screens and
> other improvements, it said in a statement.
>
> SIA said it will spend
> nearly US$150 million on improved cabin amenities on an initial eight
> Boeing 777-300ER aircraft.

These paragraphs talk about the high-end facilities that have been recently implemented by SIA. These facilities (mostly) cater to passengers travelling on high-fare tickets.

And then the sentence:

> The airline is battling strong competition from Asian and Middle
> Eastern carriers, **and on the economy side from budget airlines**, which
> have grown in number in Asia.

Here, "***on the economy side***" refers to the average cost fares, or the relatively cheaper fares(as compared to the costly tickets/seats spoken about earlier).

And last, "***budget airlines***" refers to flights which are primarily meant to cater to these types of economic fares. Look at this definition of "Low-Cost Carrier" on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-cost_carrier).

> A low-cost carrier or low-cost airline (also known as a no-frills,
> discount or budget carrier or airline or cheap flight) is an airline
> that generally has lower fares and fewer comforts. To make up for
> revenue lost in decreased ticket prices, the airline may charge for
> extras like food, priority boarding, seat allocating, and baggage etc.
> Currently the world's largest low-cost carrier is Southwest Airlines,
> which operates in the United States and some surrounding areas.
>
> The term originated within the airline industry referring to airlines
> with a lower operating cost structure than their competitors. While
> the term is often applied to any carrier with low ticket prices and
> limited services, regardless of their operating models, low-cost
> carriers should not be confused with regional airlines that operate
> short flights without service, or with full-service airlines offering
> some reduced fares.

Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Thank you, Lascivious Grace. In other words, can I say that the airline is battling on the economy side from budget airlines?

Comment: Yes, you can. However if you intend to talk about just _"the economy side from [...]_" part of the sentence, you need to include _"battling strong competition"_ as well. Without it, _"the airline is battling on the economy side from budget airlines?"_ would sound awkward. One might ask- _battling what_?